# Programatically inserting click event code for dynamically generated label not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am inserting a ActiveX control Label in excel sheet using VBA code. Now after inserting the button, I am trying to insert the click event code but its not working. Below is the code:

```
Public Function AddButton(strSheetName, counter)
Dim btn As OLEObject
Dim cLeft, cTop, cWidth, cHeight
Dim CodeModule As Object
    With Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("J" & (6 + counter))
        cLeft = .Left + 1
        cTop = .Top + 1
        cWidth = .Width - 2
        cHeight = .Height - 2
    End With
    With Worksheets(strSheetName)
        Set btn = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, Left:=cLeft, Top:=cTop, Width:=cWidth, Height:=cHeight)
    End With
    btn.Object.Caption = "Add New"
    btn.Name = Left(strSheetName, 3) & counter
    Set CodeModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
    CodeModule.InsertLines CodeModule.CreateEventProc("Click", btn.Name) + 1, vbTab & "MsgBox ""Hello world"""
End Function
```

Button is getting inserted but click event code is not working. When I click nothing happens. Also this function is getting called in a loop. First time it adds button and then as soon as it tries to add click event code, loop terminates which means there is an error.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is in continuation to your last question.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5
        AddButton "Sheet1", i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub AddButton(strSheetName As String, counter As Long)
    Dim btn As OLEObject
    Dim cLeft, cTop, cWidth, cHeight

    With Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("J" & (6 + counter))
        cLeft = .Left
        cTop = .Top
        cWidth = .Width
        cHeight = .Height
    End With
    With Worksheets(strSheetName)
        Set btn = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=True, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=cLeft, Top:=cTop, Width:=cWidth, _
        Height:=cHeight)
    End With
    btn.Object.Caption = "Add New"

    btn.Name = Left(strSheetName, 3) & counter

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents( _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Click", btn.Name) + 1, _
        String:=vbCrLf & _
        "MsgBox ""Hello world"""
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> yes, Clean the code from a particular sheet of entire Excel project. That's what is the requirement – user1269291 54 secs ago

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim strSheetName As String

    strSheetName = "Sheet1"

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents( _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).CodeName).CodeModule
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents( _
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Click", btn.Name) + 1, _
        String:=vbCrLf & _
        "MsgBox ""Hello world"""
    End With

With this code it is inserting the click event code but when I click on lable, msg box is not coming that means the code is not executing just it inserts the click event code in the sheet's code behind file

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, its up now. I have a tool to develop in a technology(Excel VBA) that I don't know at all. But it goes on this way in my company. Your help is very much valuable

Comment: With this addition, if I am deleting the buttons dynamically through the code, it wont delete the click code that we generated from the above code. Is there any way to delete the click event code when button is being deleted by the code.
For deleting the buttons I am doing the following

Comment: No suppose 5 buttons are added through the code, only there click event code(generate from the code again) is there and all the code need to be deleted because all the buttons will be deleted in one shot

Comment: Then we can write a general code to clean of all the code from sheet1. would that do?

Comment: yes, Clean the code from a particular sheet of entire Excel project. That's what is the requirement