# Handling Events for OLEObject CommandButtons created at Runtime

Tags: events, vba, event-handling, ole, commandbutton

I have struggled with this problem for while now...I want to do something very simple. I want to create multiple commandbuttons at runtime, and then handle events for these commandbuttons with one procedure. So I have built a "withevents" class to handle the automation, but my code is not working. When I run Test(), the CommandButton is created, but when I click on it...there is no messagebox response...I cannot find the error..Please any help would be great!!

Class cTest

```
Public WithEvents Button As MSForms.CommandButton

Public Sub Button_Click()
s = MsgBox("Hello", vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Module 1

```
Public TestCollection As Collection

Sub Test()

Set TestCollection = New Collection
Dim Btn As CommandButton
Dim OLEBtnObj As cTest
Set OLEBtnObj = New cTest
Set Btn = Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", link:=False,_ DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=368.25, Top:=51, Width:=44.25, Height:=24).Object
Set OLEBtnObj.Button = Btn
TestCollection.Add Item:=OLEBtnObj

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe worksheet controls (.OLEObjects.Add) appears to re-compile the project. If you want, try working with Form Controls and assign an `.OnClick` event to it or if you still want to use the ActiveX Control then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633387/programatically-inserting-click-event-code-for-dynamically-generated-label-not-w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have one rather impractical solution. To test it place the following code in *Sheet Class Module* (see attached image). The `Me.CodeName` refers to [Code-Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) of the sheet.

For each new Sheet1-button a new event handled will be added. This event handler will execute the *common event handler* and pass the name of the clicked command button to it.

```
' Standard Module
Sub test()
  ' adds three buttons to Sheet1 with click-event handlers
  Sheet1.AddButton
  ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Activate
  Sheet1.AddButton
  ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Activate
  Sheet1.AddButton
End Sub

' Sheet1 Class Module
Option Explicit

' Add Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility

Public Function AddButton() As MSForms.CommandButton
  Dim msFormsCommandButton As MSForms.CommandButton
  Set msFormsCommandButton = Me.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1").Object
  CreateEventHandler msFormsCommandButton.Name
  Set AddButton = msFormsCommandButton
End Function

Private Sub CommonButton_Click(ByVal buttonName As String)
  MsgBox "You clicked button [" & buttonName & "]"
End Sub

Private Sub CreateEventHandler(ByVal buttonName As String)
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim codeText As String
    Dim LineNum As Long
    
    Set VBComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Me.CodeName)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    LineNum = CodeMod.CountOfLines + 1

    codeText = codeText & "Private Sub " & buttonName & "_Click()" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "  Dim buttonName As String" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "  buttonName = """ & buttonName & "" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "  CommonButton_Click buttonName" & vbCrLf
    codeText = codeText & "End Sub"
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, codeText
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank God!! THis def works...After extensively looking at this issue, It is not possible to build a wrapper class for dynamically created OLEObjects using "withevents" keyword. The only solution is to programatically insert new code in the Sheet module for every object created...though this is def not the most elegant solution, it works. THanks so much daniel!! And for future reference, do you think this would have been much easier to implement using Visual Studio Tools for Office. I thinking about getting familiar with that API..and using VSOT instead of VBA form now on...

Comment: Hi Sunny, i am glad it was usefull for you. I did not found another working solution for OLE buttons on sheet except of this one. Getting familiar with VSTO is very usefull. On the other side VBA is definitelly much easier to work with.

Comment: I copied the code and the problem is that `Me.CodeName` raised an error :  Method or variable not found
I tried the autocompletion and I didn't find `Me.CodeName`

Comment: @NASSIMADRAO Code should go into `Sheet1 Class Module` and you have to add reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility`, have you done it that way?

Comment: @DanielDušek What is `Sheet1 class Module` ? I can add classes not linked to a sheet in vba , and I can add code in `Sheet1` module

Comment: @NASSIMADRAO Sheet1 Class Module is what you refer to as Sheet1 module. I have edited the answer, hope this helps to understand it better.