# Adding OLE Object Command Button in VBA stops it from executing code

Tags: excel, vba

The following script is supposed to create a button and by code make it execute code when clicked. The problem is that i cant get the subroutines to work when executed in a separate subroutine.

```
Dim cmdArray As New CmdHandler
Dim i As Integer

Sub AddButton()
    Dim oTB As Object
    Set oTB = Worksheets(1).OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
    oTB.Name = "MyButton"
End Sub

Sub AddEvent()
    Dim objButton As CommandButton

    Set objButton = Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("MyButton").Object
    Set cmdArray.CommandButtonEvent = objButton
End Sub
```

The subroutine `AddButton` creates a Command Button in the Excel Worksheet, and `AddEvent` in company with the following class module will make the button show a Message Box with "Success!" when clicked.

```
' Class module called "CmdHandler"
Public WithEvents CommandButtonEvent As CommandButton

Private Sub CommandButtonEvent_Click()
    MsgBox "Success!"
End Sub
```

The script work if I first run subroutine `AddButton` manually and then `AddEvent`. But running them consecutively in a separate subroutine fails to make the button show the Message Box.

```
Sub Execute()
    AddButton ' The button is created as normal
    AddEvent ' Some part of the AddEvent subroutine fails
End Sub
```

I struggle with debugging this problem because when stepping through with `F8`, I am faced with Excel telling me that the program `Can't enter break mode at this time`, at `Set objButton = Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("MyButton").Object`.

Is this just a VBA Excel bug? If so, is there any workarounds?
Am I doing something wrong? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Ah Ok. I misunderstood you. Yes I believe worksheet controls (.OLEObjects.Add) appears to re-compile the project. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994235/handling-events-for-oleobject-commandbuttons-created-at-runtime) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633387/programatically-inserting-click-event-code-for-dynamically-generated-label-not-w)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for guiding me to these similar questions. I were afraid that the solution would be to insert new subs line by line, as it is in the cases you linked to, but thanks anyway.

Comment: quick question.. why not use a form control?